# How to Clone Git Repo from one account to another

Tags: git, repository, clone

We have 2 account in git. both have separate repositories. 
Example 
Account 1 : Repository - ABC, XYZ 
Account 2 : Repository - PQR 
Now we want to clone repository XYZ from Account 1 to Account 2.

We know how to cloe a reporsitory within account, But from different account is a question. 
We tried but no success. Need your guidance on performing such operation.

Comment: Git does not have accounts. Git does no user authentication. Other things—operating systems, and hosting sites like GitHub, for instance—do have accounts and *do* perform this sort of thing, but that's not a function of Git at all. You'll need a different forum (perhaps also on StackOverflow, but not [tag:git]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GitHub or GitLab.
I would suggest you forking the repository with a different account.